# Ionic push notification - $ionicPush.saveToken() return status 404

Tags: ionic-framework

I implement push notification on my app as per the tutorials in https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/. I inject `ionic.cloud` to the module and my code is like this

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $ionicUser, $ionicPush, $log) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        $ionicPush.register({}).then(function(token) {
            console.log(token);
            return $ionicPush.saveToken(token, {
                ignore_user: true
            });
        }).then(function(t) {
            console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
        });
    });
})
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicCloudProvider) {
    $ionicCloudProvider.init({
        "core": {
            "app_id": "a2bbf72e"
        },
        "push": {
            "sender_id": "863453354920",
            "pluginConfig": {
                "ios": {
                    "badge": true,
                    "sound": true
                },
                "android": {
                    "iconColor": "#343434"
                }
            }
        }
    })
})
```

The token is generated successfully.But `$ionicPush.saveToken()` return status 404 like this.
[Please click here to view console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDTMD.png)

Can Anyone help for this issue?

Thank U

Comment: did you find solution for this?

Comment: Yes.I was using cordova 5.X. I updated to 6.X..And also updated the push notification plugin..Now its working..